# Константный метод, вызывающий неконстантный метод

Tags: c++, классы, доступ, константа

У меня класс (допустим `A`) и класс у которого он наследуется (допустим `B`), к которому у меня нет доступа(библиотеку установил). Внутри класса `A` я определил функцию `void foo() const`, но внутри которой есть функция из `B`, которая как раз таки противоречит константности.

```
class B
{
public:
    void notConstFunction();
};

class A:public B
{
    void foo() const
    {
        notConstFunction(); // Выдает ошибку.
    }
};
```

Могу ли я создать исключение? Обойти как-то и при этом оставить  `const` перед `foo()`

Comment: Так а почему тогда ваш `foo` константен? Где именно возникает противоречие? Неправильная библиотека, в которой забыли `const`? Или дело в другом?

Comment: Как и написал Harry, я знаю как влияет данная функция на обьект(конечно она меняет параметры), просто она меняет такие параметры, которые никак не важны для моей программы(я их не использую).Просто вызов данной функция сбрасывает значения параметров, но я их и не использую, но при этом функция производит вывод на экран и вычисления.

Comment: Ну так может вам тогда лучше сделать `B` mutable членом `A`, вместо того, чтобы использовать наследование? Откуда взялось наследование в вашем коде? Оно действительно необходимо?

Comment: Да, действительно. Я просто на Qt пишу. Наследую `QTextEdit`(в Qt все по-моему и основано на наследовании и `connect`-ах)

Comment: Это явно проблема XY. Обычно нет никакой необходимости делать const_cast mutable или еще как-то извращаться для вызова неконстантных методов. То бишь либо этот метод действительно не надо вызвать из константного метода.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если вы точно знаете, что `notConstFunction()` не будет изменять сам объект - ну что ж, со всем пониманием, взятием на себя ответственности и иже с ними, пишите

```
void foo() const
{
    const_cast<A*>(this)->notConstFunction(); // НЕ Выдает ошибку.
}
```

Т.е. вы просто константный указатель временно делаете неконстантным...

Answer (score 0):

Если метод не изменяет обьект (забыли обьявлять константным или не придали значения), я не вижу разницы для какого обьекта его вызывать(если они в одинаковых состояниях). Для примера  напишем с каким нибудь определением:

```
void B::notConstFunction()
{    
  std::cout <<"the function \"notConstFunction\" " 
            << "does not change the object";        
}
```

Тогда константная функция производного класса может вызвать `notConstFunction` и для другого обьекта, и результат будет тот же, что вы ожидали получать, к тому же не нужно будет снять константу с вашего обьекта:

```
class A:public B
{
public:
    void foo() const
    { 
        A b = *this;        
        b.notConstFunction();
    }
};
```

Используйте на здоровье:

```
A a;
a.foo();
```

Comment: "...я не вижу разницы для какого объекта его вызывать" - это как это??? O_o А если поведение метода зависит от текущего содержимого объекта?

Comment: @AnT,   поправьте меня, потому что я вполне могу не так выразится... Да, я описал слышком частный случай, но можно брать обьект с таким же состоянием

Comment: Брать объект с таким же состоянием, т.е. копию, наверное, можно. Но, во-первых, это неэффективно. И, во-вторых, как получить это "такое же состояние" если, скажем, объект является некопируемым?

Comment: @AnT, вы правы, вполне может быть и некопируемым, но на это то же есть решение...  А копировать неэффективно только в случаи  больших обьектов. Но если задача такая, то эффективность уже второй вопрос... Ну а как быть тогда? Скажите вы сами.